# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space which objects are getting all the memory?

Tags: java, xslt

I have written some code that seems to explode in terms of memory.

I don't understand why since most of the objects are created in supplementary methods and I would expect the space to be free after the end of the method.?!?(or not?)

I am rather new to the memory consumption subject. And I do not know what to do to improve it.

Configuring the JVM by adding the flag -Xmx8192 did not help. It only got me to process 3 more packages. (initially27 packages processed with -Xmx flag I reached 30)

Could I delay it somehow to give time to the GC to free space?
Or would this not help?

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
    public class mainToTest{

        public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException{        String str;       
          String home = "C:/Users/Eirini/Desktop/OP/";      
          String s = "13092017-1800";       
          File Descriptor;          
          final Charset ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;      
          Path path = Paths.get(home+"output.xml");         
          List <String> LOP= new ArrayList();
          LOP.clear();      

          List<String> lines;
          int i,j;

          File [] a =(new File(home+s)).listFiles();          
          System.out.println("Packages found...");      
          for (i=0; i<a.length; i++){           
            System.out.print("For package " + i);             
            Descriptor=findDescriptor(a[i]);             
            XSL.transformation(Descriptor,new File
            (home+"extractprocedureid.xslt"));

            lines  = Files.readAllLines(path, ENCODING);             
            str=lines.get(1);           
            if (LOP.isEmpty()){
            LOP.add(str);}          
            for(j=0; j<LOP.size(); j++){
            if(!(str.equals(LOP.get(j)))){
                   LOP.add(str);}           
            }
          }         
          System.out.println("");       
          System.out.println("Finished Procedures found:");         
          for (i=0; i<LOP.size();i++){          
             System.out.println(LOP.get(i)); }


    }


        public static File findDescriptor(File pckg){       
           String s;        
           int i,k;         
           int j=0;
           File[] ind=pckg.listFiles();         
           System.out.println(" all Items and descriptor listed");

           k=ind.length;

           for (i=0;i<k;i++){           
               System.out.println("File " +i);          
               if (ind[i].getName().endsWith("_immc.xml")){
                  j=i;
                  i=200;
                  System.out.println("Descriptor found !!!!");                 }            
               else{
                 System.out.println(" not a descriptor. Moving to the next");}      }       

            return ind[j];              

        } 
}
```

and the XSL.transformation looks like that

```
public static void transformation (File immc,File xslt){

        Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(immc);
        Source xsl = new StreamSource(xslt);
        Result xmlOutput = new StreamResult(new File("C:/Users/Eirini/Desktop/OP/output.xml"));

        try {
                Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl);
            transformer.transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);
        } 
        catch (TransformerException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception caught");
        }
        System.out.println("XSLT transformation finnished...The result can be found in file C:/Users/Eirini/Desktop/OP/output.xml");

    }
```

The error usually happens right after the XSL.transformation (2nd piece of code)

Thanks

Comment: Just profile it. By the way `-Xmx8192` gives just 8kb of memory, try `-Xmx8192m` instead. (But I'll assume it was just a typo.)

Comment: How large is the output of these transformed files? For every file that you transform, you are reading the lines of text and appending to the `LOP` ArrayList. So, you will be holding the output of all of these transformed files in memory. Try not appending to your `LOP` to see if things remain constant, or invoke `LOP.clear()` after each file to see if you stop throwing OOM errors and then tune from there.

Comment: yes  my exact command was  java -Xmx2048m -Xms512m mainToTest

Comment: the files after the transformation is 2-5 lines

Comment: lexicore what do you mean by profile it?

Comment: ok I think I found it  ... It has a bug it adds the same String over and over in the for loop. for(j=0; j<LOP.size(); j++){
            if(!(str.equals(LOP.get(j)))){
                   LOP.add(str);}           
            }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem is the lines:

```
   for(j=0; j<LOP.size(); j++){
       if(!(str.equals(LOP.get(j)))){
          LOP.add(str);}           
       }
```

This snippet will double the size of the list LOP every time you have a new value for str.  So you have an exponential memory usage just there.